# Javascript: scrollBy function executed on a div

Tags: javascript, scroll

I have a div with `overflow: scroll;` And I would like to put a button. When you press it, the content of the `div` scrolls.

Something like:

```js
function scrollDiv() {
  document.getElementById("d").scrollBy(100, 100);
}
```

```html
<div id="d">
  <p>Click the button to scroll by 100px.</p>
  <button onclick="scrollDiv()">Click me to scroll!</button>
</div>
```

This works in FF, but not in Chrome. In Chrome I get

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

The `scrollBy` function seems to be defined as `window` function, so I guess this is the problem, and it's working in FF not by standard.

But is there another way to do that? I am not using jQuery, and I'd rather not.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can try this:

```
function scrollDiv(){
    document.getElementById("d").scrollTop += 100;
    document.getElementById("d").scrollLeft += 100;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this works perfectly! Thanks for taking the time to help

Comment: Yes, this works perfectly! can u please tell how to reverse back to right after going to left  document.getElementById("d").scrollLeft += 100;

Comment: Is there a way to have a smooth transition like in jQuery?

Answer (score 4):

Rather than do

```
function scrollDiv(){
   document.getElementById("d").scrollTop += 100;
   document.getElementById("d").scrollLeft += 100;
}
```

would you not do

```
document.getElementById("d").scrollBy({
   top: 100,
   left: 100,
   behaviour: 'smooth'
})
```

Comment: This won't work if the browser doesn't provide the `scrollBy` method on elements. At point of writing this includes Edge and IE 11.

Answer (score 0):

To continue @Pavel answer.

If you want smooth behavior, you can add `scroll-behavior: smooth;` to the `d` element

```
#d {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```